# Not enough values to unpack when using split function

Tags: python

Here I'm trying to make a sub-list from list, and I'm getting "Not enough values to unpack error.

If I use `k=s.split(',')` it shows the error, whereas if I use `k1=[s.split(',')]`, it doesn't show any error while unpacking.

Both have the same type, same size and same-content

**My code:**

```
inputs = ["1, foo, bar", "2, tom, jerry"]
outputs1=[]
for s in inputs:
    print(s)
    k=s.split(',')
    print(k,type(k),len(k))
    k1=[s.split(',')]
    print(k1,type(k1),len(k1))
    for (x, y, z) in k:
        outputs1.append([int(x), y.strip(), z.strip()])
print(outputs1)
```

Comment: your `for` loop is wrong, just  do `x, y, z =  k` then `outputs1.append([int(x), y.strip(), z.strip()])`. Note, this will fix your issue but there is no doubt a better way to code this entire block

Comment: `outputs1 = [[int(k) if k.isdigit() else k.strip() for k in k.split(',')] for k in inputs]`

Answer (score 2):

Using `k`, you have a tuple with three elements, and in `for (x, y, z) in k` you try to unpack *each* of those three elements to three more element. This does not work. Using `k1`, you have a list with a single three-elemented tuple inside. Here, `for (x, y, z) in k1` *would* work, but it's entirely pointless.

Instead, you should unpack the values directly to `x, y, z`:

```
for s in inputs:
    x, y, z = s.split(',')
    outputs1.append([int(x), y.strip(), z.strip()])
```

Answer (score 0):

`k = s.split(',')` this is where the error occours.

`s.split(',')` in your case returns 3 strings. Buy on the left hand side theres only one variable k. You cannot assign 3 variables to only one variable.

changing it to 
`k1, k2, k3 = s.split(',')`
will work

Comment: No, it is not. It _can not_ occur there, as there's no tuple unpacking. It's this line `for (x, y, z) in k:`

Comment: ah yes, I was checking that just now! guess I learnt something today!

Comment: How k1 was able to hold 3 strings if they both have same syntax except for a square bracket [ ]?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
inputs = ["1, foo, bar", "2, tom, jerry"]
outputs1=[]
for s in inputs:
    print(s)
    k=s.split(',')
    print(k,type(k),len(k))
    k1=[s.split(',')]
    print(k1,type(k1),len(k1))
    for (x, y, z) in k1:
        outputs1.append([int(x), y.strip(), z.strip()])
print(outputs1)**
```

Outputs1:

```
[[1, 'foo', 'bar'], [2, 'tom', 'jerry']]
```

I'm just fixing your code but there is much better way to write this code

Answer (score -1):

You need `for (x, y, z) in k1:` instead of `for (x, y, z) in k:`.

Comment: Yeah my question is what's the difference between k and k1. I know k1 works the way I wanted. Please clarify my doubt.